# IndexError in my python script

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I am using ActivePython 2.7.5.6 (ActiveState Software Inc.).  I get error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\python scriptname.py", line 9, in 
    host = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

When I change `sys.argv[1]` to use `[0]`, I get the same error but it substitutes `argv[1]` for `argv[2]`. What's wrong here?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Simple Gohpher Client - chapter 1 - gopherclient.py

import socket, sys


port = 70

host = sys.argv[1]
filename = sys.argv[1]

s = socket. socket(socket.AF_INET, socket. SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))

s.sendall(filename + "\r\n")

while 1:
    buf = s.recv(2048)
    if not len(buf):
        break
    sys.stdout.write(buf)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing enough arguments on the command line. Pass more.

Comment: can you give me an example? I am new and still in the learning process. The book am using doesn't elaborate. ( also, the book has argv[1] and argv[2])

Comment: `python script.py foo bar`

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell exactly what you expect people to pass on the command line, but this:

```
host = sys.argv[1]
filename = sys.argv[1]
```

should probably be this:

```
if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    sys.stderr.write("Not enough arguments.\n")
    sys.stderr.write("Usage {0} <host> <filename>\n".format(sys.argv[0]))
    sys.exit(1)

host = sys.argv[1]
filename = sys.argv[2]
```

---

If you want the filename to default to the hostname, change this to:

```
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    sys.stderr.write("Not enough arguments.\n")
    sys.stderr.write("Usage {0} <host> [<filename>]\n".format(sys.argv[0]))
    sys.exit(1)

host = sys.argv[1]
if len(sys.argv} == 3:
    filename = sys.argv[2]
else:
    filename = host
```